# inverse trigonometric functions in traditional form

Tags: traditional-form

Is there a way to have 'arcsin' rather than 'sin^-1' as arcsin in TraditionalForm? I couldn't find any way to set options for customizing the way in which expressions are turned into traditional form, and feel that 'arcsin' is widely more used among mathematicians than sin^-1.
Thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: If you can replace `ArcSin[x]` by `arcSin[x]` and then give a format statement for this: `Format[arcSin[x_]] = StandardForm[ArcSin[x]]`